# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'process_commands'

Tags: python, discord.py

My code for my bot (discord.py) Is returning this error
`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'process_commands'`|

here is my code

```
token = os.environ['TOKEN']
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
api_token = os.environ['api_token']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return  # Ignore messages sent by the bot itself

  if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
    # Check if the bot is mentioned in the message
    prefix = "!!"
    response = f"My prefix is `{prefix}`, you can run !!help to get started."
    await message.channel.send(response)

  if not message.author.bot:
    server_id = str(message.guild.id)
    config = load_config()
    response_data = load_response(
    )  # Load the response data using load_response function

    if server_id in config:
      command = message.content[len("!!"):].split(' ')[0]

      # Check if the command is in the config for the server
      if command in config[server_id]:
        response = config[server_id][command]
        await message.channel.send(response)

      # Check if any word in the message matches a response
      for word in message.content.split():
        if server_id in response_data and word in response_data[server_id]:
          await message.channel.send(response_data[server_id][word])
          break  # Stop checking after sending a response

  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

discord.py, using slash commands.

I tried using other methods but nothing worked, for example using break or something that didnt make sense I was really desperate to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line: `bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)` to `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!" , intents=intents)`

Comment: I'm using .Client for slash commands. would changing it to that break it?

Comment: I don't understand how you are using .Client for slash command. From what I saw in your code, you are using `app_commands.CommandTree(bot)` as slash commands. So in this case it would not change a thing. But anyways it worth a try, at last you change it back.

Answer (score 0):

`process_commands` only exists with [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot). There are two ways to make slash commands; with `discord.Client` and [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot).

Because slash commands doesn’t need the bot to read messages, using `bot.process_commands` is actually pointless.

`discord.Client` method:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

client = discord.Client() #  Good practice to name your variables accordingly
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name=“mycommand”)
async def mycommand_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=“Hello!”)
```

And with [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=“/“)
tree = bot.tree
```

On a side note, you are also missing message content privileged intents, so on_message event wouldn’t be able to read any messages.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```